# Submit/Trigger a form within a browser using firebug or chrome:debugger

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, firefox

I have come across a problem with my friends browser. On a website, a from which didnt allow me to check a checkbox and execute the form using the associated button.

I went into firebug/chrome:debugger(inspect element) and added the obvious checked="checked" to the input.

But how can I trigger the form, I can see the name, maybe call javascript from within the debugger?

Could i use this?:

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: In case you use jQuery, `$('#formid').submit()` should suffice

Comment: But how can I achieve this? Where do I run this code, not in the console surely? I've just tried it and no success